# Renaming fails for duplicated objects

Tags: python, duplicates, rename, maya

I am making a renaming script, but I am getting in a bit of trouble with my
Seach and Replace function.

Actually, the function works as long as there are no duplication of the same
object in the hierarchy. For example, as depicted in the attachment, locator1
and locator2 are created from scratch, whereas locator3 is a duplication from
locator2

[image]

If I were to display them in their short name, it is as follows:
locator1
locator2
locator2|locator3

So as mentioned, when I tried to replace the word 'locator' to 'Point', the
renaming works for locator 1 and 2, but when it comes to locator3, I got the
error `RuntimeError: No object matches name`

As such, I was wondering if there is a better way for me to recode, cause in
cases like in Modelling, where artists duplicates the object over and over again
or using of instances..

I know that this fails is due to the short name in itself but is it possible to bypass it?

```
def searchReplace(self):
    wordSearch = str(self.searchTxt.text())
    wordReplace = str(self.replaceTxt.text())

    objCnt = cmds.ls(sl=True, sn=True)

    if len(objCnt) == 0:
        self.searchTxt.clear()
        self.replaceTxt.clear()
        cmds.warning('Nothing is selected')
    else:
        for wordString in sorted(objCnt):
            if wordSearch in wordString:
                newWordString = wordString.replace(wordSearch, wordReplace)
                cmds.rename(wordString, newWordString)
                self.searchTxt.clear()
                self.replaceTxt.clear()
                print '%s' %wordString + " has changed to : " + "%s" %newWordString
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem, but the solution is actually really simple!

When you sort `objCnt`, you're doing it lexicographically:

```
    for wordString in sorted(objCnt):
```

This means that `locator2` comes before `locator2|locator3`. On its own that should be fine, but...

When `locator2` is renamed, the path to `locator3` has also changed, so accessing it fails.

The trick is to reverse the sort so *longer* objects come first. That way the children always get renamed before their parents

```
    for wordString in sorted(objCnt, reverse=True):
```

For this to work, you also need to make sure your `ls` gives you long names, be adding the `long=True` argument

Comment: I think lexical sorts are enough in this case, so sorted(objCnt, reverse=True) on long names should be the same effect.  OP can get the short name of that with wordString.split("|")[-1] on the long names